# Accessing Results tool in progress?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We have installed results tool in our existing progress installation.

Does results tool allow only one user to log in?

I use the following command to access Results tool

```
mresults dbname
```

If I'm logged in then the other user is not able to log in to results tool. He gets the following error:

**License not available  for this product.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query/Results for Unix does support multi-user support for the database.

Check that you really have started a multi-user server and aren't just accessing the db file directly.

Also there could be a licensing limitation - have you installed all licenses?

Run this command to list all licenses:

```
showcfg
```

Comment: Yes jenscd,i can see the licensing information for all the products.And now we are connected to Results tool.but we dont know  exactly why we get that error before.